# How to highlight a part of code block in markdown

Tags: markdown, syntax-highlighting, highlight

I want to highlight a part of a code block that is written in markdown using triple backticks (```).
Here is an image of what I want.
[code block with highlighting-imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYwVk.png)

**I want to replicate how we highlight a sentence in a book with a highlighter/marker** .
I have used the `<pre></pre>` and `<mark></mark>` but these tags dont work inside code block as seen below;

````
```
<pre>
<b>some bold text</b>
<pre/>
```
````

Comment: Which Markdown tool are you using? Plain Markdown doesn't do anything like that (or provide syntax highlighting in code blocks, for that matter).

Comment: I am using plain markdown and thanks for the info. I was searching for a way but it doesn't exist.

Comment: In that case you'll have to rely entirely on HTML for that section. Remove the `\`\`\`` fences and just use `<pre><code>...</code></pre>`.

Comment: That could be done, but I would have to compromise on syntax highlighting for different languages. But I see no other way of doing it, this is the closest possible solution. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Well again, Markdown itself _doesn't do_ syntax highlighting for source code. You must be using a particular tool that adds that.

Answer (score 3):

I use [rehype-prism-plus](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rehype-prism-plus) and a mdx library [next-mdx-remote](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-mdx-remote) together.

> `rehype-prism-plus` is a rehype plugin to highlight code blocks in HTML with Prism (via
> refractor) with additional line highlighting and line numbers
> functionalities.

With `next-mdx-remote` the setting is very simple:

```
import { serialize } from "next-mdx-remote/serialize";
import rehypePrism from "rehype-prism-plus"

const mdxSource = await serialize(markdownContent, {
    mdxOptions: {
      remarkPlugins: [],
      rehypePlugins: [rehypePrism], //  here it is
    },
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

- Currently word only highlights in yellow.
- Use plain HTML around "word" with CSS to do the highlighting, colorization, etc.

For the people who are wondering what the suggested solutions in the answer above are all about, here it is.

- They are Node.js plugins (packages). You can install them in your Node environment and run the corresponding HTML through them. I would call the result transpiled HTML, similar to transpiling Coffee Script in regular JavaScript because JavaScript does not have features available in Coffee Script.
- Markdown does NOT have the ability to highlight single words, so the suggestion is to "pipe"/pass what you have to this Node package, and it will spit out the HTML needed to highlight the specific word.
- The problem is that it does not scale. You have to transpile every time. The idea is to just put a tag around the word you want to highlight, similar to word, which only does it in yellow.